# Issue in list view css

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want the following structure with ul

```
_________________________________

     1      2       3       4
_________________________________

     5      6       7       8
_________________________________

     9      10
```

But I am unable to produce that last line. My output is

```
_________________________________

     1      2       3       4
_________________________________

     5      6       7       8
__________________

     9      10
```

You refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tmp38/

Please help.

Comment: Why do you need it to be `<ul>` instead of `<table>` ?

Comment: Actually my html structure is in <ul> and cant change that as I dont want to use tables

Comment: Wouldn't it be ok to have lines at the bottom, too?

Comment: how do you generate the list?

Comment: check out this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tmp38/15/) please it may help you

Comment: the data comes dynamically and the number of li in particular row changes according to resolution. so I cant find the number of li in that row

Comment: the data in the list is dynamic

Comment: is js an option. if not you need to lock you screen size because as far as I know there is no fill function for lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if js is no problem here is a dynamic solution. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T9B3m/3/)
it first looks how many `li` fits in a row and then looks at the last row to see how many are missing. lastly it adds a padding to the right based on the size of a `li` and the number missing

Comment: yep don't know an other way. just like you what to know if there is a way without JS but don't think there is

Answer (score 2):

Check the no of li attribute you want to display in first row and then put remaining empty  `<li>&nbsp;</li>` in last row .

Else convert your structure with **div** .

Check it :
 http://jsfiddle.net/varunk007/EMG2F/5/

Comment: I cant find the number of li in that particular row as the data is dynamic and number in row changes with the resolution

Comment: Rohan : just check it http://jsfiddle.net/varunk007/EMG2F/3/, I have run with jquery , and also you can optimize it more :)

Comment: change the width of li and check the result .

Comment: you and me had the same idea, only mine adds padding yours empty `li`

Comment: :) ... without js I dont think its possible with li & css. curious to know if there is any way .

Comment: me two. as far as I know there is no fill function within css for lists

Answer (score 0):

You either have to add blank li elements like:

```
<ul class="packages">
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>1</li>
    <!--ADD BLANK -->
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Or set custom class for 7 and 8 to have border on bottom:

CSS:

```
.border-bottom {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="packages">
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
     <li>4</li>
     <li>5</li>
     <li>6</li>
     <li class="border-bottom">7</li>
     <li class="border-bottom">8</li>
     <li>9</li>
     <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

There is many ways you can go about this, it just depends on what your trying to accomplish. Here is an example with nested elements.

CSS:

```
.packages li
{
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 30px 0;
    width:176px;   
    padding-top:30px;  
    border-top
    text-align:center;
}
.packages ul {
    border-top:1px solid #444;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 352px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="packages">
 <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
     <li>1</li>
 </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: you can also add a `padding-right` for each missing `li`. like if you miss 2 and they are all 50px large you add a `padding-right:100px;` [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tmp38/16/) <--example

Comment: Yes, however you would have to make multiple styles depending on how many spaces are missing, for instance if there was only one missing it would be 50px, two 100px and three 150px, that would accumulate to three different styles. This would be a great solution however if this list is only going to be implemented once.

Comment: you can fix that simply with a littel math and js